# How to a set some text based on the contents of a radiobutton?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, radio-button

I have a fairly basic C#/WPF question.  I have a listbox that I can add radio buttons into. I set the listbox selection mode to 'single' so I can only select one at a time. What I want to do is based on what button is selected set some text based on the radio button content.

My code snippet looks like this:

```
private void Btn_Hello(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{          
    RadioButton rb = selection.SelectedItem as RadioButton;      
    Hello_box.Text = "hello" + rb.Content;  
}
```

When I run my code however the `selection.selecteditem` is null.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you doing something like in this post=> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42134/RadioListBox-A-ListBox-with-Radio-Buttons-WPF-Vers ?
Because the ListBox default is like this post http://wpftutorial.net/ListBox.html You have to do some custom binding (like in the first post) To make it work with Radio Buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void Btn_Hello(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      RadioButton rb = selection.Items.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.IsChecked==true);
      if(rb!=null)
          Hello_box.Text = "hello" + rb.Content.ToString();
  }
```

I think this should help if I understood your question correctly.